# How to group and ungroup in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr, tibble

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
test_df <- data.frame("SN" = c("ABC123","ABC123","ABC123","MNO098","MNO098","MNO098"), 
                      "code" = c("ABC1111","DEF222","GHI133","","MNO1123","MNO567"), 
                      "d_time" = c("2220-08-27","2220-05-27","2220-02-27","2220-11-27","2220-02-27",""))
```

[image]

I am trying to do 2 things

1) create 2 new columns (`p_id`,`v_id`) by stripping alphabets from columns `SN` and `code` and retain only 9 digits

2) create a lag column (`p_vid`) based on `v_id` for each person sorted based on his/her `d_time`

```
t_df <- test_df %>% group_by(SN)
t_df %>% arrange((d_time), .by_group = TRUE) ->> sorted_df #sorted based on d_time
transform_ids = function(DF){  # this function is to create person and visit_occurrence ids
  DF %>% 
    mutate(p_id = as.integer(str_remove_all(.$SN,"[a-z]|[A-Z]") %>%   #retaining only the numeric part
                                    str_sub(1,9))) %>%
    mutate(v_id = as.integer(str_remove_all(.$code,"[a-z]|[A-Z]") %>% 
                                              str_sub(1,9))) %>%
    group_by(p_id) %>%
    mutate(pre_vid = lag(v_id)) %>%
    ungroup
}
transform_ids(sorted_df)
```

But when I do this I encounter the below error

> Error in View : Column `p_id` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 6
>   Error: Column `p_id` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 6
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In view(transform_ids(t_df)) :
>    Show Traceback
>    Rerun with Debug
>    Error: Column `p_id` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 6

I expect my output to be like as shown below. Basically I am trying to link each `v_id` of a person to his previous visit which is `p_vid`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the `p_id` and `v_id` columns, just use `sub`:

```
t_df$p_id <- gsub("[A-Z]+", "", t_df$SN)
t_df$v_id <- gsub("[A-Z]+", "", t_df$code)
```

For the `p_vid` column, use `lag()` from the `dplyr` package:

```
t_df %>%
group_by(p_id) %>%
mutate(p_vid = lag(v_id, order_by=d_time, default=0))
```

The output from the above actually gives you a tibble.  If you want a data frame, just use:

```
t_df <- as.data.frame(t_df)
```

Output:

```
  SN     code    d_time     p_id  v_id  p_vid
  <fct>  <fct>   <fct>      <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ABC123 ABC1111 2220-08-27 123   1111  222  
2 ABC123 DEF222  2220-05-27 123   222   133  
3 ABC123 GHI133  2220-02-27 123   133   0    
4 MNO098 ""      2220-11-27 098   ""    1123 
5 MNO098 MNO1123 2220-02-27 098   1123  567  
6 MNO098 MNO567  ""         098   567   0
```

Comment: Don't we have to ungroup it to get the output as a dataframe? I would like to pass the processed dataframe to another functiom

Comment: In addition, can you see my updated expected output?

Comment: Your code also does the same thing/produces same output. Right?

Comment: I take it back, your expected output looks correct to me now.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen - How to restrict the number of characters after strip to just 9. If you see in my code, I have used `0-9`. Similarly can you let me know how to do it in gsub?

Comment: Is this the elegant way to do `substr(gsub("[A-Z|a-z]+{0,1}", "", t_df$SN),0,9)`?

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do (I don't want to venture a guess).

Comment: Let's say instead of extracting all digits (after strip), I would like to extract/retain only the first 2 digits. In this case, the output for `p_id` for first 3 rows would only be `12` and for next 3 rows, it would just be `09`

Comment: @SSMK You could actually handle this using a single call to `sub`, e.g. `sub("^[A-Z]+(\\d{2}).*$", "\\1", "ABC1111")` which outputs `"11"`

Comment: May I know what does `*$` and `\\1` indicate here? In my case numbers can be between alaphabets or at the start. All I know is string will be a mix of numbers and alphabets

Comment: Then in this case you should remove all letters and then take a substring from the start of just 2 characters.  Do not use my comment above in this case.  `substr(gsub("[A-Z]+", "", "ABC1DEF1"), 1, 2)`

Comment: Thank you. last question. Don't we have to ungroup? When do we use `ungroup`?

Comment: You don't need an ungroup operation here, because the output still contains all the originated unaggregated rows of the input data frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201706/discussion-between-ssmk-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: Hi, can help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200536/r-unable-to-install-r-packages-cannot-open-the-connection